# how linux shows its desktop on screen at kernel-level

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, desktop

I have some question about linux desktop environment.

1. How linux shows its desktop environment on a screen. I mean *where* and *how* its GUI frames generates and send to lcd driver? is it at kernel level? does it have any relation to frame buffer (such fb0)?
2. Is it possible to access the Desktop GUI of linux and write it on frame buffer to show the window environment of linux?

I have searched a lot but did not find my main answer that how linux Desktop Environment is created and shown by monitor that have been known by drivers on linux.

thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux there's no internal desktop or anything like that. desktop environments are just regular applications just like other applications. almost all desktop environments at their lowest level interact with another GUI library (e.g **Qt**, **GTK**, ...). then all these GUI libraries interact with lower-level software called **windowing system** or **display server** or **window server**.

In Unix systems most used window system is **X window system** ( simply called as **X** or **X11**). almost any GUI library which supports Linux, it works with X.

**Wayland** is another windowing system which is growing and is supposed to be a good replacement for X, because X window system is too old and have many issues. but X is used almost everywhere in Linux and other Unix based operating systems.

So if you really want to know what's going on down there, you should know **linux graphics stack**. as i said desktop environments are just high level applications. from windowing system (like X) to lower-level libraries and modules (KMS, DRM, ...), are what you really looking for.

KMS (kernel mode setting) works with display controller and DRM (direct rendering manager) works with graphics card and GPU. (however it's really not as simple as i explained)